# Fourier series trigonometric bn/an value

Tags: integration, fourier-series

So how would do below Fourier?

where $$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
1-x, &x = [0,4]\\ 
x-3, &x = [4,8]
\end{cases}$$

Should is this way to solve it?

$$b_n = \frac{1}{8}\int_{0}^{4} (1-x) \cdot \cos(\frac{2\cdot \pi\cdot n\cdot x}{4})dx +\frac{1}{8}\int_{4}^{8} (x-3) \cdot \cos(\frac{2\cdot \pi\cdot n\cdot x}{4})dx$$

Comment: more like $y(x,t) = \ldots$

Answer (score 1):

It is in fact$$b_n = \frac{2}{8}\int_{0}^{4} (1-x) \cdot \cos(\frac{\pi\cdot n\cdot x}{4})dx +\frac{2}{8}\int_{4}^{8} (x-3) \cdot \cos(\frac{\pi\cdot n\cdot x}{4})dx$$since the period is $T=8$ and $L={T\over 2}=4$.

Comment: Wait should be 2/T so [Link](https://www.codecogs.com/eqnedit.php?latex=bn&space;=&space;\frac{2}{8}\int_{0}^{4}&space;1-x&space;\cdot&space;cos(\frac{pi\cdot&space;n\cdot&space;x}{4})dx&space;&plus;\frac{2}{8}\int_{4}^{8}&space;x-3&space;\cdot&space;cos(\frac{pi\cdot&space;n\cdot&space;x}{4})dx)

Comment: Such a mistake! Yes you are right. Thanks.

Comment: I doing some other problem, it not usual for both an and bn to be zero for standard question right? Would that just be straight line/wave.

Comment: Well it depends on whether you classify a **Taking FT from $\cos \omega t$** question as standard or not :) But yes. Mostly, the questions give you a (normally) continuous function over a limited interval that need to be extended periodically outside.